# Randomly select a line out of a text file and set that line as a variable

Tags: batch-file

How to randomly select a line/ip out of a text file, and set it as a variable.

I mean something like:

```
set IP=TheLine/IPFromOfTheFile
```

Answer (score 3):

The array based solutions seem like they ought to be fastest because they only read the file once. But variable manipulation becomes very slow when the environment becomes very large. So the array based solutions give non-linear performance. They can be painfully slow if the file is very large.

For a pure batch based solution that gives decent linear performance, regardless of file size, I like [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832818/1012053). However, it has problems with lines that begin with `;` due to the default for /f EOL value. It also fails if the file is empty. Here is a corrected version that is nearly perfect.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=test.txt"
set "LINE="
for /F %%N in (
  'type "%file%" ^| find /C /V ""'
) do set set /A RND=%RANDOM% %% %%N 2>nul || goto :BREAK
if %RND%>0 (set "skip=skip^=%RND%") else set "skip="
for /F usebackq^ %skip%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%file%") do (
  set "LINE=%%L"
  goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
set LINE
```

There is one remaining flaw with the above - If the selected line is empty, then it will return the next non-empty line instead due to the design of FOR /F.

The "standard" way to fix that is to use FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number, and then use expansion find/replace to remove the prefix. Given the presence of the line number prefix, I like to use an additional FINDSTR to select the correct line, rather than relying on FOR /F

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=test.txt"
set "ln="
for /f %%N in (
  'type "%file%" ^| find /c /v ""'
) do set /a rnd=%random% %% %%N + 1 2>nul || goto :result
for /f "delims=" %%L in (
  'findstr /n "^" "%file%" ^| findstr "^%rnd%:"'
) do set "ln=%%L"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
:result
set ln
```

If you know that all your lines are <= 1021 bytes long, then there is a simpler solution for dealing with empty lines that reads the file with SET /P instead of FOR /F.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=\utils\jrepl.bat"
set "ln="
for /f %%N in (
  'type "%file%" ^| find /c /v ""'
) do set /a rnd=%random% %% %%N 2>nul || goto :result
<"%file%" (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %rnd%) do set /p "ln="
  set "ln="
  set /p "ln="
)
:result
set ln
```

Just for yucks, I decided to write a solution based on my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). An optimized hybrid JScript/batch script could be written, but JREPL is convenient if you already have it in your bag of tricks.

If all you need is to print a random line, then it is a simple one liner:

```
call jrepl "^.*" $0 /c /jmatch /jbeg "rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*cnt)+1" /jbegln "skip=(rnd!=ln)" /f test.txt
```

A bit more code is needed to get the value in a variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ln="
for /f "delims=" %%L in (
  'jrepl "^.*" $0 /c /n 1 /jmatch /jbeg "rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*cnt)+1" /jbegln "skip=(rnd!=ln)" /f test.txt'
) do set "ln=%%L"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
:result
set ln
```

If the lines are all <= 1021 and you don't mind a temp file, then you could use SET /P

```
@echo off
setlocal
call jrepl "^.*" $0 /c /jmatch /jbeg "rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*cnt)+1" /jbegln "skip=(rnd!=ln)" /f test.txt /o temp.txt
set "ln="
<temp.txt set /p "ln="
del temp.txt
:result
set ln
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to know the number of lines present in the text file `textfile.txt`:

```
for /F %%N in ('type "textfile.txt" ^| find /C /V ""') do set NUM=%%N
```

Then calculate the random number in the range from `0` to `NUM-1`:

```
set /A RND=%RANDOM%%%NUM
```

Finally pick the line from the text file and store it in `LINE`. `RND` holds the number of lines to skip by the `for /F` loop:

```
if %RND% EQU 0 (set "SKIP=") else (set "SKIP=skip=%RND% ")
for /F "usebackq %SKIP%delims=" %%L in ("textfile.txt") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
```

This relies on the fact that the text file does not contain any empty lines.

Comment: You need to escape your pipe in your first `for /F` loop.  But having two `for /f` loops + `type | find` is less efficient than the single `for /F` loop suggested in other answers.  The only advantage to this would be if OP's script has more than one instance of pulling a random IP out of his data file, and the data file might have been modified between instances.

Comment: Yes, @rojo, I forgot to escape the pipe; i don't know if the pipe is even necessary (I posted the answer from my mobile...), but I'll test it; anyway, I posted this answer because both `for /F` loops are iterating once only which might be of good overall performance (only having a pure batch-file solution in mind)...

Comment: @rojo - Not necessarily true. Variable manipulation becomes very expensive when the environment becomes very large, which makes performance non-linear. So the "array" based solutions seem like they should be fastest because they only read the file once. But in reality they can become a dog if the file is very large. This answer provides a solution that provides overall good linear performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load file lines into "line" array
set "num=0"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("theFile.txt") do (
   set /A "num+=1"
   set "line[!num!]=%%a"
)

rem Select one random line
set /A "rnd=%random% %% num + 1"
set "IP=!line[%rnd%]!"

echo %IP%
```

For further details on array management in Batch files, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Answer (score 1):

If I had gotten to this question earlier, I might've written Aacini's answer pretty much identically.  He gets a +1 from me.

Anyway, how about something different for a little variety?  Here's a batch one-liner that invokes a PowerShell helper.

```js
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell "get-random (gc \"%file%\")"') do set "IP=%%I"
```

It's slower than Aacini's solution, but it does have the advantage of simplicity.  *shrug*  If your IPs file includes any empty lines, you can add a selector to include only lines whose truthiness doesn't evaluate to false / empty.

```js
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell "gc \"%file%\" | ?{$_} | get-random"') do set "IP=%%I"
```

I'd also thought about getting a count of the lines in the text file using `find /c /v "" txtfile` then using `for /f "skip=%randomLineNumber%"` (like aschipfl's answer), but that'd be less efficient than the other answers already offered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=somefile.txt"
set "lines=0"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do set /a "lines+=1"
set /a "selected=%random%%%%lines%"
set "lines=0"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
if !lines! equ !selected! set "line=%%a"
set /a "lines+=1"
)
echo %line%
pause
```

Answer (score -2):

My solution is essentially identical to Aacini's but with a few differing details:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%1) do (
    set line[!i!]=%%x
    set /a i += 1
)
set /a j=%random% %% %i%
set ip=!line[%j%]!
```

The file name is an argument to this batch.